# Handling Exception

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, combobox, aspxgridview

I have a temporary table with gridview( MaterialGrid) which inserts,update n delete values from grid on save button click.

`Material_id` is primary key for gridview n it does not allow duplicate material entry through combobox(which is in MaterialGrid),while inserting duplicate material it throws exception in bindmaterialGrid function.

I want to handle this exception n display message box

```
"cant insert duplicate material"
```

how to solve it?

Comment: Be more specific please. How about using an exception handler?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of throwing and catching Exceptions, you should have to check the `existence` of primary key column value.

Answer (score 0):

Don't wait for exception to be thrown, rather have a check before hand and see if the value being inserted is already present. Using this approach, you will have more control on the execution flow and you will also avoid the overhead of processing exception.